# Как убрать лишние значения из вывода?

Tags: python, dataframe

Составил функцию для анализа данных колонки датафрейма.

```
def test(df, colx):
  dfx = df[colx]
  a1 = pd.DataFrame(dfx.value_counts())
  a1['percent'] = round((a1[colx] * 100 / len(df)), 2)
  a2 = display(a1, f'Процент незаполненных значений: {round((100 - a1.percent.sum()), 2)}')
  return a2, df.loc[:, [colx]].info()

test(menu, 'soop') # функция вывода
```

Но при выводе получаются лишние данные.

```
   soop percent
GP  349 88.35
MS  46  11.65
'Процент незаполненных значений: 0.0'
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 395 entries, 0 to 394
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   soop  395 non-null    object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 3.2+ KB
(None, None)
```

А именно последняя строка (None, None) мне не нужна.
И строку 'Процент незаполненных значений: 0.0' нужно избавить от кавычек.

Comment: А что за функция `display` и как вызывается функция `test`? В приведённом коде нет того, что повлияло бы на вывод тем образом, как вы описываете.

Comment: Вызов функции добавил в вопрос. А display используется для того, чтобы вывести таблицу в JupiterLab в красивом виде.

Comment: Это в интерактивном питоне происходит? После `test` что-то ещё в коде вызывается?

Comment: Нет, описан только вывод функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас интерактивный питон, например `Jupyter Notebook`, то он выводит на печать результат выполнения последней команды в ячейке. Если последняя команда у вас вызов функции `test`, то, соответственно, `Jupyter Notebook` выведет на печать то, что возвращает функция `test`, а она у вас возвращала, видимо, два `None`: `display` и `df.info()` печатают информацию на экран и возвращают при этом `None`. Решения тут на самом деле возможно два:

- не возвращать ничего из функции `test` (убрать `return`)
- добавить знак `;` в конец строки с вызовом функции `test` и тогда `Jupyter Notebook` не будет печатать результат выполнения этой функции

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение сам. Всем спасибо за участие!

```
def test(df, colx):
    dfx = df[colx]
    a1 = pd.DataFrame(dfx.value_counts())
    a1['percent'] = round((a1[colx] * 100 / len(df)), 2)
    b1 = round((100 - a1.percent.sum()), 2)
    display(a1), print(f'Процент незаполненных значений: {b1}'), df.loc[:, [colx]].info()
```